# Google Maps Service v3: 'ERROR' returned on Geocoding

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I've got a Google Maps widget working on an .xhtml page served by a JSF2 project in Java. The map displays, and I have a function for adding markers that works just fine. However, any attempt to use Geocoder seems to result in the returned status of 'ERROR'. Google Maps API mentions no such error status amongst its five possible candidates for return values of the 'status' variable.

Followng is a .js file deployed, and the offending function in question is codeAddress(). Similar code to codeAddress() works elsewhere online that I can find, so it must be something to do with the circumstances under which its being called. Given that the map displays just fine, and I can place markers, my expectation is that my session is just fine. This leaves me puzzled :( Does anyone know what 'ERROR' could come from??

```
var map;
var marker;
var geocoder;

function placeMarker(location) {
 if (!marker) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: location,
          map: map
      });
  } else {
      marker.setPosition(location);
  }
  map.setCenter(location);
  var field = document.getElementById("portCreate:coordinate");
  field.value = "POINT (" + location.lat() + " " + location.lng() + ")";
}

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center : new google.maps.LatLng(55.761123, 13.084717),
        zoom : 5,
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        placeMarker(event.latLng);
    });

    setMarker(document.getElementById("portCreate:coordinate"));

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
}

function setMarker(field) {
    if (field.value) {
        var regex = /POINT.+?([-0-9\.]+).+?([-0-9\.]+)/;
        var matches = regex.exec(field.value);
        placeMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(Number(matches[1]), Number(matches[2])));
    }
}

function codeAddress(address) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status + "\nFor address " + address);
        }
    });
}

function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<API key here>&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;
```

Comment: would be important to see where you call codeAddress and what you pass as address

Comment: I switched to simply calling a dummy value of 'westlake', to avoid that being the error. I also tried 'california' and a variety of other values I know should work. I tested those same values on another site that demonstrated the v3 API, and I took a look at their source to verify I was performing the geocoding call in the same manner.

Comment: there are 5 possible [status-codes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingStatusCodes) for a geocoding-request, none of them is ERROR, so where do you get the "ERROR" ?

Comment: Hence my initial comment that 'ERROR' does not crop up as a valid status-code, and my trouble figuring out what is going on :) 'ERROR' is the status value I'm being returned, which thus subsequently also pops up in the alert() call.

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_simpleMap_geocoder2a.html)

Comment: I appreciate that the code itself works. That brings me no closer to finding out how I'm getting 'ERROR' from the Google v3 API, which is what my question was. I'm not sure how I should've phrased this differently, and why I'm getting downvotes on the question. Alas, going to edit OP Post to clarify.

Comment: Don't downvote him, I'm also getting status called 'ERROR' suddenly, it was working in the past few weeks and now I get this with every geocode I try to calculate.

Comment: While the [js geocode doc page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) only mentions 5 status codes, the [API reference page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GeocoderStatus) has some more.

Comment: The API reference page (ref by @IsaacKleinman) lists `ERROR There was a problem contacting the Google servers.` - one of my app users got this for the first time yesterday.  I can only assume he had a bad data connection and was unable to reach the google servers from his phone at that particular moment or he some how cancelled the lookup in the middle of the google trying to perform the address lookup causing the script to ERROR (as mentioned below by @Edwin Daniels).  Other than I don't know what could be causing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having this same problem today I've remembered that instead of doing a link to the API I downloaded the code as .js. After changing it to a link it works agains. I think Google updates the script regurlaly, if it had any version conflict they return the ERROR status.

Comment: I have tried to follow this, and I have had no luck if I directly import the API as the link or .js. Would you happen to know if there is anything else I might be missing?

Comment: It was the opposite for me. Pulling the JS file from the CDN works, but using the local version of the file caused some issues. (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js)

Comment: it solved my problem too.  I went from a local file to a url inclusion, which gets me the latest version

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for javascript/geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingStatusCodes) shows 'ERROR' as a possible result:

> "ERROR" indicates that the request timed out or there was a problem contacting the Google servers. The request may succeed if you try again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was working with ASP .Net application. After I changed the ASP .Net button control to HTML input Button, it is working now. Not sure where the problem is.

```
<input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress()">
```

Answer (score 0):

I was troubleshooting a similar issue, where I was able to recreate the ERROR status by canceling the google API http request before it returned a response.